# Application with ID: <id> was not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I got a problem when creating a new app in AWS Amplify. I selected the option of New App, then I connected the repo and in the end, everything looked fine but when I refresh the browser a message said: "the app doesn't exist".

[This is the error I'm getting after creating it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeqFl.png)

Comment: I know it is basic, but are you in the right region?

Comment: Yes, I am. I've been always in us-east-1 :(

Comment: Can you provide more details on the steps that lead up to this error? Alternatively, you can try to contact AWS support. Unfortunately, with the given information it's hard to help you